# SQLCMD MODE - Incorrect syntax near 'S'

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, sqlcmd

In SSMS, when I execute

```
sqlcmd -S "flynetSrv"
```

I get :

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'S'.

I am already connected to the server through SSMS

I also tried

```
sqlcmd -d "dbname1"
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near 'd'.

Please help?

Comment: Have you tried to not use the double quotes?

Comment: I have tried **sqlcmd -d dbname1** and I still get the error, and I tried **sqlcmd -d 'dbname1'** and I still get the same error

Comment: sqlcmd is a *separate* command line tool for executing SQL. You wouldn't enter a complete sqlcmd command line *into* an SSMS query window, which is what it sounds like you're trying to do.

Comment: What I understand now, sqlcmd is used it windows cmd.exe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sqlcmd` is an [utility intended to be used in a command prompt](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx)

You cannot use it in a SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) query window

You can only write or edit SQLCMD scripts within the query window enabling the **SQLCMD mode** (Query menu -> SQLCMD Mode)

From MSDN - [Editing SQLCMD Scripts with Query Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174187.aspx):

> To use the Database Engine Query Editor to write or edit SQLCMD scripts, you must enable the SQLCMD scripting mode.